# Android SQLite no data from View

Tags: android, sqlite, view

I'm developing a Android App. This App have an SQLite Database. This Database have 6 Tables an 5 Views. If I try to get Data from a View, there is no Data. At the Debugging I looked in the Cursor and the Columns are listed but not data. Count is -1.

The I copy the Database via DDMS to my PC and open it in SQLlite Manager(Firefox Plugin) and start the same Query (Copy at Debugging from Code) and there are Data from the same Database with the same query.

It is possible, that the Android Device (HTC Sensation) and the Emulator are not powerful enough to run such difficult Querys?

Comment: that would depend on the query. would you paste it here?

Comment: The Query isSelect * From view_all_sms_wcd  where  KUNO = '1'  order by ST_DTE asc

Comment: ST_DTE is the Storage date but if i try it without the order by it doesn´t work too

Comment: could you provide the SQL statement that you used when creating the view?

Comment: @Dyonisos CREATE VIEW view_all_sms_wcd AS select * from view_all_sms as vas left outer join tbl_personen as p on p.KUNO = vas.Contact_ID

Comment: In sqlite the field names in views are retrieved during the query unless you specify the field names during the view creation. is the field KUNO existing in the view_all_sms? Maybe you could try to: `Select * From view_all_sms_wcd where Contact_ID = '1' order by ST_DTE asc`

Comment: @Dyonisos The field KUNO is in the View. And if i start the same Query on the same database but on the pc not at the Android device, then i get my data..

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I have tryed it with Contact_ID and it seems to work. I have to do a few tests to make sure that it works

Comment: Ok Im gonna post this as solution then that also other users which have the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sqlite the field names in views are retrieved during the query unless you specify the field names during the view creation.

Is the field KUNO existing in the view_all_sms or is it the field Contact_ID?

Try:

```
Select * From view_all_sms_wcd where Contact_ID = '1' order by ST_DTE asc
```